# How to Change the image of UIButton when selected which is on tableVIewCell. in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, cocoa-touch

I am implementing a like dislike button on the tableview cell but unable to change the image of the button. can anybody help me out using swift 3

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {


    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    var array: [String] = ["A","B","C","D","E","F"]
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return array.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell: cell_TableTableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell_TableTableViewCell") as UITableViewCell! as! cell_TableTableViewCell!

            cell.textLabel?.text = array[indexPath.row]

        cell.button_Outlet.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.button_Outlet.addTarget(self, action: "LikePressed", for: .touchUpInside)

        return cell
    }

}


func LikePressed(sender : UIButton){

    sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected    
}
```

Comment: You forgot to add code in question

Comment: just  a normal table view and a single button . later I will implement it into the project . can u pls help me . @Mike Alter

Comment: See the @KavyaKavita 's answer and implement it

Comment: Please elaborate more. Where do you want to change the image. If you want to make the image static, do change it from Storyboard. Else use didSelectItemAt method

Answer (score 2):

While designing your custom cell, you can add image for that button for different states

1. Default
2. Selected

When you add selector for that button, in that selector you just need to change button's selection state

```
func buttonTapped(sender : UIButton){

        sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected


}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple, for example your button is from storyboard. Add make that it **custom button**.

**1)** And add **tag** value in `cellForRowAt indexPath:`.

**2)** And set two images for that butoon.

**3)** Finally fix selected sate.

See my code

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell: cell_TableTableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell_TableTableViewCell") as UITableViewCell! as! cell_TableTableViewCell!

        cell.textLabel?.text = array[indexPath.row]
    //Step 1
    cell.button_Outlet.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.button_Outlet.addTarget(self, action: "LikePressed", for: .touchUpInside)
    //Step 2
    cell.button_Outlet.setImage(UIImage(named: "LikeImage"), for: .selected)
    cell.button_Outlet.setImage(UIImage(named: "DisLikeImage"), for: .selected)
    return cell
}

//Step 3
func btnPressed(sender:UIButton) {
    if sender.isSelected == false {
        sender.isSelected = true
    } else {
       sender.isSelected = false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. IBOutlet the UIButton into your cell class(Eg. TableViewCell).
2. Write a method in ViewController class to detect buttonTap.
   Eg:

   func dislikeTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
       // set required image to sender
   }
3. In TableView-CellForRow method add target to the button in cell.
   Eg:

   cell.dislikeButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.dislikeTapped(_:), for: .touchUpInside)

Comment: dont forget to set button tag

Comment: hi @ Karthikeyan I have implemented both the answers but not working both. I have uploaded the code could you pls help me

Comment: did you reload your tableview

Comment: can you try if sender.selected { sender.setImage(UIImage(), forState: .normal) }else{ sender.setImage(UIImage(), forState: .normal)} something like that ??

Comment: Did you set correct images for different states(selected, highlighted etc) of the button on your cell xib or storyboard?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an array too to maintain the state of button as when you scroll cell that are not visible on screen are removed from memory, so they are dequeued again from one that are visible, if you not maintain the state it will use attributes of cell u dequeued  from.

```
var arrSelectedButtonswitTag = [Int]()
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell: cell_TableTableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell_TableTableViewCell") as UITableViewCell! as! cell_TableTableViewCell!

        cell.textLabel?.text = array[indexPath.row]
    //Step 1
    cell.button_Outlet.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.button_Outlet.addTarget(self, action: "LikePressed", for: .touchUpInside)
    //Step 2
    cell.button_Outlet.setImage(UIImage(named: "LikeImage"), for: .selected)
    cell.button_Outlet.setImage(UIImage(named: "DisLikeImage"), for: .normal)
    if arrSelectedButtonswitTag.contain(sender.tag)
        sender.isSelected = false
    arrSelectedButtonswitTag.remove(sender.tag)
    } else {
        sender.isSelected = true
    arrSelectedButtonswitTag.appen(sender.tag)
    }
    return cell
}

//Step 3
func btnPressed(sender:UIButton) {
if arrSelectedButtonswitTag.contain(sender.tag)
        sender.isSelected = false
    arrSelectedButtonswitTag.remove(sender.tag)
    } else {
        sender.isSelected = true
    arrSelectedButtonswitTag.append(sender.tag)
    }
}
```